# How to save mouse coordinates onbeforeunload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I can track mouse coordinates dynamically with this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $().mousemove(function(e)
{
 $('p').html("X Axis : " + e.pageX + " | Y Axis " + e.pageY);
});
});
```

With this, the numbers change on each mouse move dynamically. What I want to do is to save all coordinates. It should save it onbeforeunload. How to save all numbers ? I am thinking of append an iframe onbeforeunload like

save.php?coords=162x412-143x716-678x12

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I think there is too much information that you can't handle!

Comment: I don't know jquery too much. I am good at php/mysql. Also, I am making a project that track users professionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var moves = [];
$().mousemove(function(e){
    moves.push(e.pageX + "x" + e.pageY) 
});
```

then

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.post( your_url , moves.join('-'));
}
```

Comment: So "your_url" should look like "saveit.php?moves=" ??

Comment: Not sure if serious or trolling ? your query is missing posting value, it should be something like
$.post("test.php", { name: "John"});

Comment: I was serious!(I gave you 1 Up) but it could be like your second way too  $.post( your_url , {moves: moves.join('-')});

Answer (score 3):

try this approach...

a way of saving these coordinates in a hidden variable and calling that hidden variable values on the event "onbeforeunload" to obtain them and save necessary..

Comment: Nice. But how, could you please help me ?

Comment: These links might help..

1 .http://forum.jquery.com/topic/passing-value-to-hidden-form-field


2. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-value-of-hidden-input-field-loading-using-load